# Views: Show All Distinct Dates

Tags: datetime, views

I have a custom content type with a date field that includes year, month, day, hour and minute. If I create a view of all the node start dates I get something like this

```
2014-10-23 13:00:00
2014-10-24 18:30:00
2014-10-24 21:00:00
2014-10-25 09:30:00
2014-10-25 10:00:00
2014-10-25 13:00:00
2014-10-25 18:30:00
2014-10-25 21:00:00
```

I want to create a view that lists only the unique *days* in ascending order. If possible I'd also like to rewrite these as links. Ideally I'm looking to generate something like

```
Thursday, October 23 2014
Friday, October 24 2014
Saturday, October 25 2014
```

or even better

```
<a href='date-2014-10-23'>Thursday, October 23 2014</a>
<a href='date-2014-10-24'>Friday, October 24 2014</a>
<a href='date-2014-10-25'>Saturday, October 25 2014</a>
```

I've tried aggregating but I have to install extra modules to get the day granularity and even then I can't sort by date ASC. I've tried grouping but that just add extra headers I can't rewrite as links plus it means I still output a line for each node like this

```
Thursday, October 23 2014

Thursday, October 23 2014
Thursday, October 23 2014
Thursday, October 23 2014

Friday, October 24 2014

Friday, October 24 2014
Friday, October 24 2014

Saturday, October 25 2014

Saturday, October 25 2014
Saturday, October 25 2014
Saturday, October 25 2014
Saturday, October 25 2014
Saturday, October 25 2014
```

because the view is only using one field and if I hide it the view doesn't work. I've also used 'Distinct' and 'Pure Distinct' but they don't seem to do anything.

Is there something I'm misunderstanding? I don't get why this is so much trouble to do.

Answer (score 0):

This video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cp2SPiwA2Qg shows exactly wat you want. I ussualy follow these steps:

1. Add a second date field to the view.
2. In the configuration of that field

   1. Configure the field to only display the year
   2. Exclude the field from display
3. In the format settings of the view, group by this field.

Comment: That's not quite what I'm looking for. That view gives you

`date
--title
--title
date
--title`
I only want to show the dates, no other fields. Basically I only want to show the field I am grouping by.

Comment: Then you just have to change the title field with the date field...